# How to reconstitute an image randomly sliced?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to reconstitute an image randomly sliced using JavaScript and CSS.

I could have my image represented as a dimensional array for instance

```
imgArray = [
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7, 8],
[9, 10, [11, 12], [13, 14], 15],
[16, 17, 18, 19],
];
```

But since the sliced images have their dimensions, I thought a numbered list of images would've been enough

Would be really happy if one could help me with that, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).